# What is the difference between @BeforeTest and @BeforeSuit annotation?

Tags: selenium, testng

What is the difference between @BeforeTest and @BeforeSuit annotation? I have 2 methods with @Test annotation and one @BeforeTest method. When I ran it, a @BeoforeTest method was executed only once. Shouldn't it run before every @Test method?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer this example,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814147/9405154

If you want to call annotation before every Test method, You need to use @BeforeMethod annotation. 
Both @BeforeTest and @BeforeSuite will call only once on execution, They just have different approach on .XML suite execution.

Answer (score 0):

[@BeforeTest](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) will run per class

You probably want per test method,then use [@BeforeMethod](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):

> The annotated method will be run before each test method.
>
> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run

Answer (score -1):

@BeforeTest

this annotation will run before every test method for example

```
@BeforeTest
public void Setup()
{
System.out.println("before test");
}

@Test
public void test1()
{
System.out.println("Test1");
}

@Test
public void test2()
{
System.out.println("Test2");
}

Then output is as
 before test
 Test1
 before test
 Test2
```

where as `@BeforeSuite` this annotation will run @beforeclass

Comment: BeforeTest call only once, BeforeMethod call on every Test method

Answer (score -1):

`@BeforeTest` -

1. Any code written in the method with this annotation will run once for all methods with annotation `@Test` inside a class.
2. This is best suited for condition which is a prerequisite for all tests e.g. test 1 is view user profile, test 2 is add item to cart, test 3 is manage address, these tests are dependent on a condition that user should be logged in, so we can write login functionality in a method with `@BeforeTest` annotation.
3. It is present in same class in which `@Test` method is written.
4. This is mainly applied at method level.

`@BeforeSuite` -

1. Any code written in the method with this annotation will run once in complete suite life cycle i.e. for complete `testng.xml`.
2. This is best suited for initializing config files,creating database connections etc.
3. This annotation is mainly used in Base class of the class in which `@Test` method is present

@Edit - Changed the @BeforeTest annotation details

Comment: BeforeTest call only once, where BeforeMethod call on every Test method

Comment: @IshitaShah - Thanks for correcting me. This -1 is also a good learning. I will correct it so that others will not divert in wrong direction....