# @beforetest testng its being ignored for some reason

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, testng

I am running my Cucumber suite tests with TestNG (Selenium + Java) and getting java.lang.NullPointerException.

I realized the problem is that my @BeforeTest() is being ignored for some reason causing the NullPointer problem.

I am using the TestNG 7.0.0 (but tried to use latest Beta also).

```
@BeforeTest() 
public void setUp() {
    driver = Web.createChrome(); // it call a method that has the Chromedriver
}
```

Web.java

```
public class Web {

public static WebDriver createChrome() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", webdriver_path);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");

    return driver;
}
}
```

Output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.dsanders.steps.steps.accessing_the_Tnternet_herokuapp_com_website(steps.java:62)
at ?.Given accessing the Tnternet.herokuapp.com website(testing.feature:9)
```

Comment: is line 62 have driver = Web.createChrome(); , also share the function createChrome

Comment: hi, thanks for answer me. Question updated with the Web.java

Comment: is steps.java 62 line of file is -> driver = Web.createChrome();

Comment: hum, sorry but I did not figure out what is the problem with line 62.. because it works if I run with JUnit (annotation @Before() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
public class steps {


    WebDriver driver = null;

    public steps() {

        this.driver=Web.createChrome();

    }

@BeforeMethod() 
public void setUp() {
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
  }
}
```

Note ClassName here is `steps` if you have other class name then change the class name and constructor name.

Change the `@BeforeTest` to `@BeforeMethod`

Source:

[What is the difference between BeforeTest and BeforeMethod in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811759/what-is-the-difference-between-beforetest-and-beforemethod-in-testng)

Comment: uhumm, yes its working better now, however my @BeforeTest() is still not being executed.. the browser its opening now because it is being called from the Constructor... I've commented my Before and the browser is still opening :(

Comment: put some syso and see where it is calling in the execution cycle or it is not executing at all?

Comment: you are trying to invoke the driver for each test?

Comment: if yes then try to BeforeMethod instead of BeforeTest . source :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811759/what-is-the-difference-between-beforetest-and-beforemethod-in-testng

Comment: I did the sysouts, and the browser its being called from the Constructor that calls my class Web.java where I have the driver.get . So its not calling the Before. Tried to use the BeforeTest and BeforeMethod and both not worked. I was thinking.. maybe could be a problem in the Cucumber steps declaration? I mean every Cucumber step should be a method and should receive the @Test above.. or not? Just thinking here..

Comment: there is confusion in your understanding, Test is for TestNG not for cucumber, before is present in cucumber and tetsng both and BeforeMethod is of testng ... so it may be you are getting issue because the sequence of execution is different

Comment: change before import from testng to cucumber package it will execute for each scenario of cucumber

Comment: you are totally right, I got confused with TestNG and Cucumber.. I've changed just for @Before and all my suite executed fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it helps you