# TestNG BeforeMethod's firstTimeOnly usage

Tags: java, testng

What is the usage of [TestNG BeforeMethod's firstTimeOnly](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.9.4/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.html#firstTimeOnly--) optional element?

> If true and the @Test method about to be run has an invocationCount > 1, this BeforeMethod will only be invoked once (before the first test invocation).

It seems redundant as using [@BeforeTest](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) which is more clear

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@BeforeMethod` is invoked before **each** test, while `@BeforeTest` is invoked **once**, before any test has yet been executed.

So, it makes no sense having a `firstTimeOnly` property on `@BeforeTest`, it will only ever be executed once per group of tests, by design.

On the other hand, since `@BeforeMethod` is possibly executed several times (if test methods are executed several times using `invocationCount`), it is possible to tell TestNG to only execute the method annotated with `BeforeMethod` once.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349236/1421925) has a good example on the difference between the two annotations.

Let's illustrate the behaviour with an example:

```
public class TestClass {

  @Test(invocationCount = 2)
  public void methodOne() {
    System.out.println("executing method one");
  }

  @Test
  public void methodTwo() {
    System.out.println("executing method one");
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("before method");
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
    System.out.println("before test");
  }

}
```

This prints:

> before test
> **before method**
> executing method one
> **before method**
> executing method one
> **before method**
> executing method one

Notice that `beforeMethod()` is executed before each method, while `beforeMethod` is executed once, before any test has yet been executed. Also notice that `beforeMethod` is executed before each execution of `methodOne()`.

Now, let's add the `firstTimeOnly` property:

```
@BeforeMethod(firstTimeOnly = true)
```

> before test
> **before method**
> executing method one
> executing method one
> **before method**
> executing method one

Now, `beforeMethod()` is only executed once before `methodOne()`, even though the test is executed twice.

Comment: My question is why we need the redundant **BeforeMethod with firstTimeOnly = @BeforeTest**, both *invoked once, before any test has yet been executed.*

Comment: They are not the same. `@BeforeMethod` will still be called for every test, while `@BeforeTest` is invoked __once__, before any test is executed.

Comment: *BeforeMethod will only be invoked once (before the first test invocation)*

Comment: @user7294900 I added an example which hopefully makes you understand my point. Otherwise we are misunderstanding each other in some way...